# Not able to run Tomcat through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

It was working yesterday and now it is not. The error I get is

```
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in    production environments was not found on the java.library.path:  /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property   'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:exp1' did not find a matching property.
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1048 ms
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 04, 2014 10:17:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 04, 2014 10:18:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed     to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/exp1]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/exp1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> com.ser1.Hello in     servlet mapping
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3217)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3192)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1304)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1352)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
at     org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Mar 04, 2014 10:18:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed     to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Mar 04, 2014 10:18:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component      [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Mar 04, 2014 10:18:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 702 ms
```

After this server will not start . 
I have looked around for a solution for several hours now. But I have not had any success and it likely is something simple. I have tried the following:

1. Delete Serve and remake it in eclipse
2. Restart computer, eclipse
3. Reinstall eclipse, tomcat
4. Start Eclipse with -clean
5. Start server with no web app
6. Increasing the timeout

Comment: The problem it this: Invalid <url-pattern> com.ser1.Hello in     servlet mapping ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it this: Invalid  com.ser1.Hello in servlet mapping. Check the mapping in your web.xml.